# Exception handling inside fixture of test class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jdbc, exception

The line within **<s></s>** causes a *ClassNotFoundException* to be thrown and must be handled in order to compile. If I resolve the compile error by surrounding with try-catch then each unit test will be working with an uninitialized instance if the exception was thrown. What would happen if I add `throws` to the method signature?

```
@Test
public class PanelControllerTest {

    private PanelController panelController;

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {

        panelController = <s>new PanelController();</s>

    }
}
```

I'm new to test fixtures and I'm assuming this would be a correct way to test an instance of the class. What's the best way to handle exceptions inside the test fixture setup code?

**UPDATE:** 
This seems to be the source of the exception called from PanelController:

```
class DBAccess {
    public DBAccess(DBConnection dbConnection) throws ClassNotFoundException {
         Class.forName(Constants.jdbcDriver);
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to figure out why it's throwing, and eliminate the condition that's causing it to throw.

Comment: Hi, if it is the expected behaviour then I would have a test case to test this expected behaviour.

Comment: Does it throw an exception every time, or is that it *can* throw an exception, disrupting the unit tests?

Comment: @NathanielFord I added "if the exception was thrown" to my question. Its only if it happens to not work.

Comment: Update: I updated my code to show where the exception is happening as @RobertHarvey mentioned.

Comment: What would happen? Your test method would compile, and if the exception was thrown, your tests wouldn't run.

Comment: @DaveNewton that seems to be the expected behavior I would want. Without a jdbc connection (from the exception) my entire program would be in an invalid state and I wouldn't want to run the tests. So the solution would be to add the throws declaration to the method signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct behavior is to capture the exception and fail the test run.

```
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
  try{
    panelController = new PanelController();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    fail("Test failed because dependency could not be instantiated. Exception was:"+e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

In an ideal world you probably wouldn't be dependent on a db (because it's hard to manage their state for testing) when running tests, but use a mock object instead. Still, if you have to rely on it best to fail the test run if the db is out of order, and surface that as a direct failure.

Comment: Nice answer! This is what I need to do. Also, I like the idea of having a mock object for non-DB testing. Thanks!